Error in an Azure build pipeline generating swagger docs for a web API
In a Terraform .yaml file, I've got the following task:
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: 'Generate OpenAPI definition for ${{ parameters.DocumentName }}'
   inputs:
     command: 'custom'
     custom: 'swagger'
     arguments: 'tofile --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\openapi_specs\${{ parameters.ApiFileName }} $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\unzipped_artifact\$(ApiStartupName) ${{ parameters.DocumentName }}'

However I receive the following error:
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Connection String Invalid: InstrumentationKey is required.

Detailed error:
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe swagger tofile --output D:\a\1\s\openapi_specs\swagger.json D:\a\1\s\unzipped_artifact\Returns.API.dll v1
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Connection String Invalid: InstrumentationKey is required.
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Endpoints.EndpointProvider.GetInstrumentationKey()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.SelectInstrumentationKey(TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration configuration, TelemetryModules modules, String serializedConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration configuration, TelemetryModules modules)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TelemetryConfigurationOptions..ctor(IEnumerable`1 configureOptions, IOptions`1 applicationInsightsServiceOptions)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithFewArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

Any suggestions on what I've missed at this same pipeline was working a few days ago?

Hi, as you mentioned that the same pipeline was working, can you please check if there are any changes in your code, the software version or other settings? You can also try to run the command in your local to check if the same error happens. By the way, I found the document Find your connection string. If you use this connection string in your code, you can update it and try again.

If possible, can you please share a Minimal, Reproducible code example  to better troubleshooting the issue?
